# Build fails in jenkins for java which is in Azure repo

Tags: java, azure, jenkins, azure-devops

I have configured the project in Azure Repo and Jenkins VM but when I start Build of that java project in jenkins, it fails. Please help me to resolve the issue. Jenkins console output below. Integration between Azure Repo and Jenkins was successful but when I try to click on Build Now in Jenkins it fails.

Java Project is in Azure Repo,
Jenkins is in Azure cloud vm (Ready plugins available by Azure)

```
Started by user user
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /bitnami/jenkins/home/workspace/MyShuttle
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 04536115-8271-469c-9196-66fa633da13a
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /bitnami/jenkins/home/workspace/MyShuttle/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://cloudera2019@dev.azure.com/cloudera2019/MyShuttle/_git/MyShuttle # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://cloudera2019@dev.azure.com/cloudera2019/MyShuttle/_git/MyShuttle
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.35.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://cloudera2019@dev.azure.com/cloudera2019/MyShuttle/_git/MyShuttle +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision c481534e99083921a6ff50e07bed72b1f6855a93 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f c481534e99083921a6ff50e07bed72b1f6855a93 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Added CreateMYSQLDB.sql"
 > git rev-list --no-walk c481534e99083921a6ff50e07bed72b1f6855a93 # timeout=10
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 33515
[MyShuttle] $ java -cp /bitnami/jenkins/home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.13.jar:/bitnami/jenkins/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar:/bitnami/jenkins/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /bitnami/jenkins/home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven /bitnami/jenkins/home/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-4.11.2.jar /bitnami/jenkins/home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.13.jar /bitnami/jenkins/home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.13.jar 33515
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /bitnami/jenkins/home/workspace/MyShuttle/pom.xml package -Dtest=FaresTest,SimpleTest
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.microsoft.example:myshuttle >-------------------
[INFO] Building myshuttle 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (default) @ myshuttle ---
[WARNING] The artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2 has been relocated to xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/bitnami/jenkins/home/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.9/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=/bitnami/jenkins/home/workspace/MyShuttle/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myshuttle ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /bitnami/jenkins/home/workspace/MyShuttle/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ myshuttle ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ myshuttle ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /bitnami/jenkins/home/workspace/MyShuttle/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myshuttle ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ myshuttle ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /bitnami/jenkins/home/workspace/MyShuttle/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class java/util/UUID could not be instrumented.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:140)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:101)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.PreMain.createRuntime(PreMain.java:55)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.PreMain.premain(PreMain.java:47)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: $jacocoAccess
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1999)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:138)
    ... 9 more
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at ./src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
Aborted

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.070 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-28T09:25:11Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project myshuttle: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving /bitnami/jenkins/home/workspace/MyShuttle/pom.xml to com.microsoft.example/myshuttle/0.0.1/myshuttle-0.0.1.pom
channel stopped
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

I could able to solve the issue by adding below xml in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <forkCount>3</forkCount>
    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```